# ***No rule to make target '../../../Makefile.include'. Stop

Tags: c, linux, ubuntu, makefile

I am attempting to make `TARGET=wismote`, but receiving the error above. My makefile is...

```
UIP_CONF_IPV6=1
UIP_CONF_RPL=1

CONTIKI_PROJECT = udp-echo-server

all: $(CONTIKI_PROJECT)

CONTIKI = ../../..

APPS+=powertrace
PROJECTDIRS += umt6d
PROJECTDIRS += umt6d/hmac
PROJECTDIRS += umt6d/tls
PROJECTDIRS += umt6d/ntpd
PROJECTDIRS += umt6d/crypto

PROJECT_SOURCEFILES += hmac_sha2.c
PROJECT_SOURCEFILES += addr_gen.c
PROJECT_SOURCEFILES += sha2.c
PROJECT_SOURCEFILES += set-global-address.c
PROJECT_SOURCEFILES += ntpd.c

include $(CONTIKI)/Makefile.include
```

I know that I am in the right directory, and the `Makefile.include` is also in the same directory but it is telling me:

```
*** No rule to make target '../../../Makefile.include'. Stop.
```

Comment: If `Makefile.include` is in the current directory why are you trying to include `Makefile.include` from three levels up (which is what `$(CONTIKI)` is set to)?

Answer (score 1):

You mention that your Makefile.include is in the same directory, but it is included with

```
include $(CONTIKI)/Makefile.include
```

where

```
CONTIKI = ../../..
```

which would mean you would need a Makefile.include at

```
../../../Makefile.include
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I didn't think it had to be in the directory, but the Makefile.include was sitting 4 levels above /wismote-hash instead of three, so I just edited the makefile to 'CONTIKI = ../../../..' and all is well.

Comment: @Jake O'Neill, please read http://www.contiki-os.org/start.html ... `cd contiki/ && git submodule update --init` ... Then `cd tools/cooja/ && ant run`